# Закругленные края TextBox отвратительной графики. Что сделать, чтобы качество было лучше

Tags: c#, winforms

Закругленные края отвратительной графики. Что сделать, чтобы качество было лучше

```
        GraphicsPath gPath = new GraphicsPath();
        gPath.AddArc(0, 0, textBox1.Height, textBox1.Height, 180, 90);
        gPath.AddArc(0 + textBox1.Width - textBox1.Height, 0, textBox1.Height, textBox1.Height, 270, 90);
        gPath.AddArc(0 + textBox1.Width - textBox1.Height, 0 + textBox1.Height - textBox1.Height, textBox1.Height, textBox1.Height, 0, 90);
        gPath.AddArc(0, 0 + textBox1.Height - textBox1.Height, textBox1.Height, textBox1.Height, 90, 90);
        gPath.CloseFigure();
        textBox1.Region = new Region(gPath);
        gPath.Dispose();
```

Comment: Использовать WPF =)

Comment: Спасибо, классный совет. Вопрос в том как сделать это в WinForms

Comment: Невозможно сделать сглаживание региона. Попробуйте обходной способ, как сделано [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33882272/5045688).